# how to include visual c++ redistributable in your Visual C++ application?

Tags: visual-studio

how to include visual C++ redistributable in your Visual C++ application so that it can run on any machine which has no visual C++ redistributable installed.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/redistributing-visual-cpp-files

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/deploying-visual-cpp-application-by-using-the-vcpp-redistributable-package